# Weighted sum of normal r.v.s is positive with probability greater than 1/2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $N_1, N_2$ be iid $N(0,1)$ random variables. Is there a random variable $X$ that is *only dependent on $N_1$* and with magnitude less than 2 (i.e. $|X|<2$) such that
$$\mathbb{P}(N_1 + XN_2 > 0) \neq \frac12?$$
Clearly $X$ can't be constant by the symmetry of the joint distribution $(N_1,N_2)$; for the same reason it cannot be piecewise constant. I think the value of $X$ has to be some direct function of the *value* of $N_1$. I'm at a loss as for what $X$ can be.

Comment: Think about the Bernoulli case: Let's say you have a Bernoulli variable $N_1, N_2$ over ${-1, 1}$; and you are looking for the probability that $N_1 + XN_2 > 0$. If $N_1$ were positive, how can you make sure that that sum is positive? Similarly, if $N_1$ is negative, if you just put a really big constant for X what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ take value $0$ if $N_1>0$ and value $1$ otherwise.

Then $$P(N_1+XN_2>0)=$$$$P(N_1+XN_2>0\mid N_1>0)P(N_1>0)+P(N_1+XN_2>0\mid N_1\leq 0)P(N_1\leq0)=$$$$1\cdot\frac12+P(N_1+N_2>0\mid N_1\leq 0)\cdot\frac12>\frac12$$